# Image cant be updated

Tags: php, html, laravel, media

I am using Laravel media library for adding images to media collection

The image can be created successfully but it cant be updated

Here is the update code:

```
 $item->update($data);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $item->media()->delete();
        $item->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('items');
    }
```

also tried

```
$item->media()->delete($this);
```

and

```
 $item->clearMediaCollection('image');
```

but the same result is stuck in the old image.

in a blade bage:

```
                     <label for="file-upload" class="btn">
<span>
<i data-feather="image" class="ml-1"></i>
    {{__('Upload image')}}
</span>
                            <input class="hidden" id="file-upload" name="image" type="file"/>
                        </label>
```

I tried dd($request)
the updated image was shown in the request but I don't know why it is not updated.
can anyone help?

Comment: what do you mean by it did not update? in DB? or in the FileSystem?

Comment: it doesnt updated in the DB

Comment: maybe because you are ` $item->update($data);` before associating the file with your media collection

Comment: I tried to add the  $item->update($data); in the end of the code, but the same essue